# how to put a specific size to a column in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a gridview with these columns: Comment (255 char), user name(varchar 50), rating (int 1), date (yyyy-mm-dd).  Now when this gridview is showing up it put the comment in one big cell.  I will like the text to be wrap up on many lines (let say 50 chars).

Here is how I will like the gridview comes out :

## Comment                                             user name                   rating  date

aaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBaaaaaaaaaa  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb     4     2014-01-31
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

Here is the code behind

```
    SqlConnection con = new 
        SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    //======= Insert Query.

    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Comments VALUES (@comment,@user,@rate, @date)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

    //===== Adding parameters/Values.

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", txtComment.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtSignature.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", lstbxRating.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    int nbrRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    if (nbrRecords >= 1)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here is the .aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="comment" HeaderText="comment" ReadOnly="True" 
             SortExpression="comment"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user" HeaderText="user" ReadOnly="True" 
             SortExpression="usager" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rate" HeaderText="rate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="rate"
             />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="date" 
            />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed size to your cell, and then set the white-space to pre-wrap:

```
.className { 
   white-space: pre-wrap!important;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap!important; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap!important;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap!important;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word!important;      /* IE */
}
```

(apply the class to your cell).

Comment: where and how do you set the fixed sized ?

Comment: Wrap the Grid in a div, give it a class, create a css class `.grid td:first-child {...}` this will select the first child of the grid, given that the div you wrapped it with has the `grid` css class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did... just add ItemStyle-Width="" property... easy no ?

Here is the code in the .aspx

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
          <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="comments" HeaderText="comments" ReadOnly="True" 
                   SortExpression="comments" ItemStyle-Width="1500" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="userr" HeaderText="usager" ReadOnly="True" 
                   SortExpression="usager" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="rating" HeaderText="rating" ReadOnly="True" 
                   SortExpression="cote" DataFormatString="{0:0/5}" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" ReadOnly="True" 
                   SortExpression="date" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" />
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```